# Delete an sdf file in use?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

Im trying to delete an sdf file in the .NET mobile framework, but I get a "File in use" Exception. How do I disable the file so I can delete it?

I want to replace the sdf file with a new sdf file.

Comment: I would consider adding a tag related to SQL Server Compact Edition. 'sqlce' seems to be the most frequently used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server Compact Edition databases (sdf is the extension for database files) are hosted in process, you will need to close any connections and possibly stop any processes that had them open to delete this file.

Typical candidate processes that can cause this problem are the application itself, Visual Studio or SQL Server Management Studio.